# search functionaliy not working in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i am using socket.io or getting live crypto prices . it gives new prices each 10second. i have applied search functionality to get live price. but on every 10 sec my serach function get reverted and go back to normal state .

my code is below

```
const Item = ({ name }) => {
return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text>{name}</Text>
    </View>
);
};

const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item name={item.name} />;
const App = () => {

    // this.arrayholder = DATA;

  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setdata] = useState("");
  const [dasta, setdsata] = useState(DATA);

  const [error, seterror] = useState(null)
  const [searchValue, setsearchValue] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    // setLoading(true);
   var yui =  socket.on("chat", (data) => {
     setdata(data)
   });
  // console.log(yui.data)
  }, []);


searchFunction = (text) => {
    const updatedData = data.filter((item) => {
      const item_data = `${item.name.toUpperCase()})`;
      const text_data = text.toUpperCase();
      return item_data.indexOf(text_data) > -1;
      });
      setdata(updatedData)
      setsearchValue(text)

};


    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <SearchBar
        placeholder="Search Here..."
        lightTheme
        round
        value={searchValue}
        onChangeText={(text) => searchFunction(text)}
        autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
    </View>
    );

}
```

can u help pls . like when i search bitcoin it shows me bitcoin but after 10 seconds and it shows all the coin name .
you can also [see here promblem](https://www.veed.io/view/65df629a-053b-4990-a2e2-4f4a154d580c?sharingWidget=true)

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. Please explain your problem without the need for us to watch a video.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain a current search state persistent although new coins are added to the list  you should call the  **searchFunction** with the searchValue
Like

```
searchFunction(searchValue)
```

after getting the latest coin list
As previous value is saved in searchValue it will filter again your list
Form mine understanding without testing your code I assume you are getting you new data in useEffect

```
var yui =  socket.on("chat", (data) => {
     setdata(data);
   });
```

So here call

```
searchFunction(searchValue)
```

After

```
setdata(data);
```

Or Simply replace your useEffect with

```
useEffect(() => {
    // setLoading(true);
   var yui =  socket.on("chat", (data) => {
     setdata(data);
     searchFunction(searchValue);
   });
  // console.log(yui.data)
  }, []);
```

Comment: So i shouldn't use onchangetext? What I have to edit in search function

Comment: Aman Singh 1M can you replace your useEffect with this useEffect(() => {
    // setLoading(true);
   var yui =  socket.on("chat", (data) => {
     setdata(data);
     searchFunction(searchValue);
   });
  // console.log(yui.data)
  }, []);

Comment: yes i have done that. it is still same . what to do